# Python: get the list of files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, directory, python-3.5

I have a program in Python (Python 3 on Ubuntu 16.04) that checks for new files in a directory (`.mp4` files are the result of segmenting a live video stream). I use `os.listdir(path)` to get the new files in my iterations. The problem is that when a new `.mp4` file is created, first an empty file is created while the contents are being appended incrementally, so the file is not yet finalized/finished/playable (usually if you look at a folder, these files are shown like no extension).

Is it possible to ignore such non-finalized files at the Python level when getting the list of files in directory? Maybe some functions or API exists for that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `glob.glob('*.mp4', root_dir=path)` should be just fine.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html